# Save Console visor content into an Array (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, dosbox

i am starting a new langange at school (Assembly), and i need to do a work for that class. I am working on DOSBox 0.74.
I need a function to save into an array all the Console content visor, but how can I do it?
I tried this,

```
salva_ecran proc
        xor     bx,bx
        mov     cx,25*80

salva:          
        mov dl, es:[bx]
        mov consoleText[bx], dl
        inc bx
        cmp bx, cx
        jb salva
        ret
salva_ecran endp
```

but it didn't work. My variable is `consoleText db  80 dup ( 25 dup (?),13,10 )`.

ps.: I am really new at this, so sorry if the question is ridiculous or the code is bad and inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`consoleText` definition is 80x27 bytes (not 25x82!), and those 13,10 are useless any way, as you will overwrite them by `mov consoleText[bx], dl`, so all you need for storage is `consoleText db 80*25 dup (?)`.

`mov dl, es:[bx]` may read video RAM of text mode, if the `es` is set to `0B800h` (not visible from your piece of code).

But the text mode video RAM in 80x25 (mode 03h I think) does use two bytes per character, first byte of pair is the extended-ASCII code, second byte is attribute with colours, see probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode and other resources. So you are reading only half of characters and half of colours, to read only all characters I think `mov dl, es:[bx*2]` would work in real mode (or use `si` instead of `bx`, in case 16b real mode can't use `bx*2` addressing mode).

New line starts in video memory right after previous line, there are no 13,10 in the video RAM, actually those are valid font glyphs (13 being a musical note IIRC), so first 160 bytes at `B800:0000` is first line of 80 characters (with colours), then at address 160 (`B800:00A0`) the second line starts immediately.

It's not clear how you verify/print the stored content, so it's hard to say what is "didn't work". Use always debugger to verify you get values as expected.

To save/restore full text mode VRAM you should of course store also colours (so 80*25*2 bytes buffer), and restore them like that, and that would work only when the running app will not change beginning of VRAM, or other VGA control registers, affecting the output (i.e. only in pristine `mov ax,3 int 10h` state). Also such store/restore will not restore BIOS cursor position and probably other BIOS variables, so if you want to really save "console", there's more to do, than just to copy VRAM content.

But overall this looks like a nice try, the code is simple and right to the point, don't worry about performance while learning basics. But learning how to use debugger effectively is essential for your future (of Assembly learning).

Answer (score 0):

Chars on screen come in pairs : char and color, so you only need to double your variable size (and the counter!) :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

some_text   db 'StackOverflow!',13,10,'$'  
consoleText db 80*25*2 dup(?)  ;◄■■ * 2

.code
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

  mov  ax, 0b800h
  mov  es, ax

  mov  ah, 9
  lea  dx, some_text
  int  21h

  call salva_ecran

  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h

salva_ecran proc
        xor     bx,bx
        mov     cx,25*80 * 2  ;◄■■ * 2

salva:          
        mov dl, es:[bx]
        mov consoleText[bx], dl
        inc bx
        cmp bx, cx
        jb salva
        ret
salva_ecran endp
```

Comment: what about at least mentioning `rep movsw` with a CX of 2000? ;)

Comment: @JoãoRodrigues, I'm still waiting for you to click on the checkmark ✔ of my answer :)